# Singular chains generated by manifolds with corners --- does it really work?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology, chain-complexes

Usually we define singular homology via the complex of singular chains:
$$C_\ast(X)=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}\mathbb Z\langle\sigma:\Delta^n\to X\rangle$$
where the right hand side denotes the free abelian group on the set of maps $\sigma:\Delta^n\to X$.

Suppose that we want the flexibility to use more general *manifolds with corners* in place of standard simplices.  So, we define an alternative chain complex:
$$C_\ast'(X)=\bigoplus_{n\geq 0}\mathbb Z\langle f:M^n\to X\rangle/\sim$$
where the right hand side denotes the free abelian group on the set of *isomorphism classes of* maps $f:M^n\to X$ where $M^n$ is a smooth oriented manifold with corners, modulo the relation that reversing orientation negates the generator (and also restricting to maps $f:M^n\to X$ for which reversing the orientation on $M^n$ gives a non-isomorphic map, just so we don't have a bunch of $\mathbb Z/2$'s floating around).  The boundary map is clear: take the sum of all the "faces" of $M^n$ (this is ok, even though some of the faces of $M^n$ may not be embedded in $M^n$).

There is an obvious map $C_\ast(X)\to C_\ast'(X)$.  Is it a quasi-isomorphism?  My guess would be that it is, but I also found I was unable to prove it after thinking for quite a while.  Surprising as it may sound, I don't even know how to, given a cycle in $C_\ast'(X)$, construct the homology class in $H_\ast(X)$ it is "supposed" to represent!

There's an obvious strategy of proof, namely "triangulate the manifolds with corners".  However doing this compatibly with the boundary map, even for a specific cycle in $C_\ast'(X)$, seems hard.

I've tagged this "reference request" since it seems that a positive answer to my question is a "folk theorem".  For instance, some quick searching revealed a paper http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509532 which claims in Theorem 5 that (a slightly different version of) $C_\ast'(X)$ calculates singular homology.  However all they say for the proof is that manifolds with corners can be triangulated (which, on its own, does not seem to me to be sufficient).

Another related construction in the literature is that of Max Lipyanskiy (http://www.math.columbia.edu/~mlipyan/SingHom.pdf), who shows that if we are only interested in the case $X$ is a *smooth* manifold, then (something very close to) the analogous complex built out of isomorphism classes of *smooth* maps from smooth manifolds with corners to $X$ does indeed calculate singular homology.  Unfortunately, his proof of this fact uses smoothness in an essential way, so I do not see how to extend it to the case I am interested in.

Comment: This seems perfectly sufficient: just don't try to construct a chain homotopy but rather handle cycles one by one. And then it seems obviously injective and obviously surjective.

Comment: I don't even see how to triangulate a single cycle (i.e. to show that the map $C_\ast(X)\to C_\ast'(X)$ is surjective on homology).  The problem is that we have to triangulate the manifolds with corners comprising a given cycle *so that the triangulations agree on the faces*.  If you think this is easy, I'd definitely appreciate seeing a careful proof.

Comment: Must the triangulations agree on the faces? Suppose we instead add an auxiliary cell whose boundary is the discrepancy between the two faces, i.e., given two triangulations of the same face $F$, triangulate $F \times I$ such that one boundary is one triangulation and the other boundary is the other triangulation. Then push that forward to $F$.

Comment: Of course, if we have a cycle $\sum(M_i,f_i)$ where each $f_i$ is an embedding, then we can build an identification space $\coprod M_i/\sim$ and triangulate that.  But how to build the identification space in general??

Comment: It would probably be easiest to just verify the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms for "manifolds with corners homology" (I think you can just follow the usual proof for singular homology nearly word-for-word).  This will show you that your homology theory is isomorphic to ordinary singular homology.  The fact that the map you wrote down is the isomorphism should just follow by meditating on naturality and the proof that homology can be calculated using cellular homology.

Comment: ps : I'm answering in the comments not because I think this is not a good question (it is!), but because I don't have time right now to write up a detailed answer.

Comment: I mostly second Andy's suggestion: if it's a quasi-isomorphism locally then it should be globally by abstract nonsense, e.g. sheaf theory. However, I'm not used to thinking so much about manifolds with corners. If $X$ is a point, and $f:M\to X$ is the unique map and represents a cycle, what is $M$ the boundary of? If we were doing bordism, the answer might be "nothing", whereas simplices can always be coned off and you still have simplices. What's the analogous situation for manifolds with corners?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it's also not clear how to verify the excision axiom (equivalently, Mayer--Vietoris).  In other words, is it always possible to subdivide a cycle so it's a sum of generators with small "diameter"?  This seems like it should be easy, but I've been unable to prove it so far.

Comment: As for your question: I don't have any promising ideas how to verify the point axiom either (I've tried the obvious strategies without success).  I'm sure it's not so hard to show that if $M^n$ ($n>0$) is a closed manifold, then it is null-homologous in $C_\ast'(\mathrm{pt})$.  But given a cycle made up of a bunch of manifolds with corners, I have no idea what to do.  The natural first step is to build an "identification space" by identifying pairs of faces (using the fact that the sum of generators is a cycle), but this space could be awful (!), e.g. not a CW complex.

Comment: I think I spoke too fast when I wrote that one can following the usual proof word-for-word; I had quickly gone through it and didn't see any obstructions, but you're right that it's not so clear.  But if it's true, then surely that's the way to go about proving it.

Comment: Supposing we know how to triangulate mflds-without-any-corners, could the (very brief) appendix by Douady-Herault "Arrondissement des varietes a coins" from Borel-Serre's "Corners and Arithmetic groups" be useful? If $C''$ is the complex generated by corner-free manifolds, then the quasi-iso $C\to C''$ seems well known, while Douady-Herault seem (but i have not studied) to exhibit a quasi-iso $C'' \to C'$, e.g. prop 4.2, 6.1.

Comment: @J.Martel: Douady--Hérault seems unrelated to me: they study manifolds with corners on their own, and never say anything about using them as generators of chain complexes to calculate the homology of other spaces.

Comment: If  you restrict $X$ to be subanalytic, then Hardt  has a description of the (singular) homology  of $X$ that involves more exotic chains: they are all images of subanalytic sest with oriented top dimensional stratum.   http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-211-00/S0002-9947-1975-0379882-8/S0002-9947-1975-0379882-8.pdf

Comment: @John: I'm a bit leery of your statement "I'm sure it's not so hard to show that if $M^n$ ($n>0$) is a closed manifold, then it is null-homologous in $C′_\ast(pt)$." This won't be true using just manifolds (as the bordism groups of a point are non-trivial), and I don't see immediately why allowing corners helps. For example, what would be the "null-homology" of the map from $CP^2$ to a point?

Comment: @GregFriedman: perhaps I spoke too quickly!  My intended first step was going to be to triangulate $M$ and then take the dual cell decomposition.  We then use this to put a mfld with corners structure on $M\times[0,1]$, where $M\times 0$ is standard, and $M\times 1$ has corners given by the cell decomposition.  This shows that $[M]$ is homologous to something a bit more combinatorial.  But you're right, it's not obvious what to do next.

Comment: Another possible way of proving such a statement would be to use the acyclic models theorem.

Comment: I tried to prove the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms for the homology based on the category of manifolds with embedded faces (a little bit better manifolds with corners) in my master's thesis. All was OK except for the excision. I could prove a result about the existence of compatible collar neighborhoods and about extending compatible triangulations. What the main problem was, however, were orientations. First of all, dividing out orientation preserving diffeomorphisms introduces torsion in the chain complex. However, as far as I remember this can be resolved by quotienting out something more.

Comment: If I remember well, a bigger problem was with proving that some relation after the application of the boundary operator vanished in the chain complex. For this one had to show that it is possible to extend compatible diffeomorphisms from higher codimension faces to a diffeomorphism of the whole manifold with faces. However, this is possible only if one face can be chosen arbitrarily (it is not always possible to extend a diffeomorphism of S^n to D^n, but it is possible if you remove a point). As far as I remember, I somehow could not overcome this... sorry for being so imprecise.